# Install libmad on Mac OS X Lion: "error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set"

Tags: macos, unix, osx-lion, mpeg

I am trying to install a program that requires the libmad (MPEG audio decoder library) library on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, but installing libmad.0.15.b results in this error:

```
version.c:1: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
```

That library installs fine on OS X 10.5. Is it a 64-bit compatibility issue? I can't find any specific instructions or documents regarding installing on Lion. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the C and C++ compilers on Snow Leopard and newer generate 64-bit binaries, not 32-bit as in older versions of OS X. The `libmad` configure script apparently hasn't been changed to cope with this, and so generates build commands that cause the 32/64 bit conflict you see.

That means one way to fix it is to force a 32-bit build.

But, it's easy enough to clue the configure script into the correct CPU type. For Lion:

```
$ ./configure x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

For Snow Leopard, change the kernel version:

```
$ ./configure x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0
```

Comment: where do you copy it to next?  /sw/bin?

Comment: Say `sudo make install`. That will set the library up correctly. Don't just copy raw `.dylib` files around.

Comment: +1 FYI: for Mountain Lion: `./configure x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0` and more generally, `uname -a` will tell you the darwin version so you can sub in appropriately for future versions.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I believe I have a better answer than Warren Young's.

By default, libmad-0.15.1b is configured to default to using `-march i486` when it is built on a *86 architecture that it doesn't recognize.  You can disable this behavior, and get it building on your 64 bit Mountain Lion platform, by changing this line

```
        i?86-*)           arch="i486" ;;
```

in ./libmad-0.15.1b/configure.ac to this line:

```
        i?86-*)           arch="" ;;
```

This should enable libmad to build for whatever architecture the system actually is, instead of forcing `i486`.